# DataTable contain no rows after loading

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ado.net

I am trying to load a DataTable with SQLDataReader but then it shows that it has no rows. I check the reader to see if it counts correctly with the while loop and it is correct which means data has been retrieved from database:

```
NpgsqlConnection sqlcon = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnectionString);
NpgsqlCommand sqlquerry = new NpgsqlCommand(sqlcmd, sqlcon);
sqlcon.Open();

NpgsqlDataReader reader = sqlquerry.ExecuteReader();

int i = 0;
while (reader.Read())
{
    i++;
}
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(reader);

var count = dt.Rows.Count;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should decide: either you're using repeated reading from datareader and populating table manually in your loop  `while (reader.Read())` or you're populating `DataTable` with `Load` method from datareader, but not both options simultaniously.

In fact, your loop "empties" datareader but does nothing useful, so there is nothing to load after it finished. Simpliest solution - is just remove this loop.

Comment: Thanks! it solved my problem. I was thinking that the reader keeps the data